# Removing All Views gets rid of OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am adding some table rows to a tableLayout dynamically and adding an onClickListener to each row- but when I removeAllViews, for some reason it gets rid of the listener too....

Here is my code for adding the data:

```
private void addTickerToTable(String ticker, String last, String chg, String pchg, String time){
    rowId++;
    int theColor=Color.WHITE;
    int rowColor=0;
    float theSize=13f;
    lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    row= new TableRow(this);
    row.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
    if(rowOdd==0){row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#343434"));rowColor=Color.parseColor("#343434");}
    if(rowOdd==1){row.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);rowOdd=-1;rowColor=Color.BLACK;}
    rowOdd++;

    row.setLayoutParams(lp);

    tv0 = new TextView(this);
    tv0.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3A54A7"));
    tv0.setTextSize(theSize);

    tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setTextColor(theColor);
    tv1.setTextSize(theSize);

    tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setTextSize(theSize);

    tv3 = new TextView(this);
    tv3.setTextSize(theSize);


    tv0.setText(ticker);
    tv0.setLayoutParams(params);
    row.addView(tv0);

    tv1.setText(last);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(params);
    row.addView(tv1);

    tv2.setText(chg);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(params);
    row.addView(tv2);

    tv3.setText(pchg);
    tv3.setLayoutParams(params);
    row.addView(tv3);


    ll.addView(row,rowCount);
    row.setId(rowId);       
    row.setOnClickListener(this);
    row.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    row.startAnimation(anim2);
    rowCount++;



    }
```

Then I have a separate method that simply resets the data-

```
    ll.removeAllViews();
    rowCount=0;
    rowOdd=0;
    rowId=0;
```

It runs perfect the first time- everything is clickable etc...but as soon as you refresh or run the reset code, all of a sudden the onClickListeners don't work...

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind- looks like I wasn't resetting my clicked variable- Oops!